# How to stop UIScrollView when leave touch

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I made UIScrollView with some UIButton inside. The problem is that when I scroll down at the end of view, it return on start. What can i do? I use this in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // step 3
    scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroll.contentSize = [self.view sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple Documentation: sizeThatFits *returns the size portion of the view’s bounds rectangle.*

So your scroll view content size is of the same size of the UIView, thats why the scroll view returns to its original position. You need to set the height of the content size to the total height of your entire content in the scroll view. Normally this is bigger, because otherwise it won't make sense to use a UIViewController.

So, use something like this and it should work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // step 3
    scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    CGSize scrollViewSize = [self.view sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    scrollViewSize.height = 800.0; // Set here the height of the total area of your ScrollView. Should be bigger than the visible area.
    scroll.contentSize = scrollViewSize;
}
```

Comment: scuse me, but i try and nothing changes.. otherwise it stop before and it doesn't show all the view :(

Comment: the 800.0 value was an example, if your content height is bigger set he height bigger.

Comment: i used 750.. cause i see in IB that view's height is this